# Features and advantages of ForkJoinWorkerThread

Tags: java, multithreading, java-7

Can anyone please explain the advantages and features of ForkJoinWorkerThread introduced in jdk 1.7 or suggest an link which explains the features.

I am trying to find its working example on Oracle and Goolge but not able to find one.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html)?

Comment: Excellent example of using Fork/Join [here](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue201.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using `ForkJoinWorkerThread`.  Use a [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) instead.  More specifically the only visible constructor is `protected` so unless you are knowingly sub-classing it, you shouldn't need to worry.

From the [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinWorkerThread.html)

> A thread managed by a ForkJoinPool, which executes ForkJoinTasks. This
>   class is subclassable solely for the sake of adding functionality --
>   there are no overridable methods dealing with scheduling or execution.
>   However, you can override initialization and termination methods
>   surrounding the main task processing loop. If you do create such a
>   subclass, you will also need to supply a custom
>   ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory to use it in a ForkJoinPool.

Would you ever actually need to implement it?

> I am trying to find its working example on Oracle and Goolge but not
>   able to find one.

If you were using a [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) and needed to override the `ThreadFactory`, you would need to implement a `ForkJoinWorkerThread` and pass it as a constructor argument.

```
public ForkJoinPool(int parallelism,
            ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory,
            Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handler,
            boolean asyncMode)
```